# Transfer all data from a Google Account to another

Tags: google-account, account-management

I have a managed Google Account and I'd like to transfer all my data, sync files, Drive, absolutely everything possible that is Google related with that account to a new Google account. Is it possible?

Or even better, am I able to just detach the account from the organization that manages it?

Answer (score 0):

To try and get "everything possible" then takeout.google.com is your best option. There's also GYB if you're just trying to get email data exported.